# Study the parity of $\cos(\pi+x)$, $\sin(\pi-x)$ and $\sin(\frac{3\pi}{2}+x)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I tried to apply the following properties:

to be even:
$$f(x) = f(-x)$$
to be odd:
$$-f(x) = f(-x)$$

**1)**

to be even:
$$\cos(\pi+x)  = \cos(-(\pi+x)) \Leftrightarrow -\cos(x) = ??$$

What is $\cos(-(\pi+x))$ equal to?

to be odd:
$$\cos(-(\pi+x)) = -\cos(\pi+x)\Leftrightarrow ?? = \cos(x)$$

Again, same problem.

**2)**

to be even:
$$\sin(\pi-x) = \sin(-(\pi-x)) \Leftrightarrow \sin(x) = ??$$

What is $\sin(-(\pi-x))$ equal to?

to be odd:

$$\sin(-(\pi-x)) = -\sin(\pi-x) \Leftrightarrow ?? = -\sin(x)$$

Again, same problem.

**3)**

I don't really know how to solve this one.

Can anyone help me solve these? Also, is there any property that I can use to solve things like $\sin(k\alpha)$, being k a constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting them up incorrectly. You need to understand function notation better: $f(-x)$ means that $\color{red}{x}$ is replaced with $\color{red}{(-x)}$, **not** that you negate something somewhere. For example, if
$$f(x)=\cos(\pi+\color{red}{x}),$$
then
$$f(-x)=\cos(\pi+\color{red}{(-x)})=\cos(\pi-x),$$
**not** $\cos(-(\pi+x))$.
Then you can continue simplifying using properties of trigonometric functions, such as formulas for sums and differences of angles. For example, there are formulas stating that $\cos(\pi+\alpha)=-\cos\alpha$ and $\cos(\pi-\alpha)=-\cos\alpha$ for any $\alpha$. So in this question we can continue as follows:
$$f(-x)=\cos(\pi+(-x))=\cos(\pi-x)=-\cos x$$
and
$$f(x)=\cos(\pi+x)=-\cos x.$$
We can see that $f(-x)=f(x)$, i.e. this is an even function.

You can handle the other ones similarly.

Comment: Thanks, I could solve the first 2 but I am having some trouble with the 3rd one. To test if it is even, I tried $\sin(\frac{3\pi}{2}+x) = \sin(\frac{3\pi}{2}-x) \Leftrightarrow ??$ and to test if it odd I did $-\sin(\frac{3\pi}{2}+x) = \sin(\frac{3\pi}{2}-x) \Leftrightarrow ??$. Could you give me a clue?

Comment: @MarkRead: There are identities for that too: $\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}+\alpha\right)=-\cos\alpha$ and $\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}-\alpha\right)=-\cos\alpha$. To be able to figure out such identities on your own, look up the sum and difference identities for trig functions.

Comment: I got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

let $f_1(x) = \cos(\pi+x)$

$$f_1(-x) = \cos(\pi-x) =\cos(\pi)\cos(-x)-\sin(\pi)\sin(-x) = - \cos(-x) $$
$$= -\cos(x) =\cos(\pi+x) = f_1(x)$$

conclusion : $f_1$ is odd

it works pretty much the same for the other functions just replace $x$ by $-x$ simplificate and conclude.

Answer (score 1):

Also, to answer your question about $\sin(kx)$, there is a way to do this.

$$\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$
$$\cos(2x) = \cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x)$$

both of which can be proved using the sum identity ($2x = x + x$). To solve something with $k > 2$, proceed like this;

$$\sin(3x) = \sin(2x + x) = \sin(2x)\cos(x) + \cos(2x)\sin(x) = ...$$
where you can replace $\sin(2x),\cos(2x)$ with the previously mentioned identities and simplify.